# add and remove existing models to a has_many relationship using nested attributes

Tags: backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

In a rails 4 application I have two models :

```
class Gallery
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :thumbnails
end

class Thumbnail
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :gallery
end
```

I populated the mongodb database with a bunch of galleries with thumbnails in them and some unused thumbnails (with a nil gallery_id).

Now on the client side I use Marionette with backbone-associations and I represent the Gallery as so :

```coffee
class Entities.Gallery extends Backbone.AssociatedModel
  idAttribute: '_id'
  urlRoot: '/galleries'
  paramRoot: 'gallery'

  relations: [
    type: Backbone.Many
    key: 'thumbnails'
    remoteKey: 'thumbnails_attributes'
    relatedModel: -> Entities.Thumbnail                                                      
  ]

  initialize: ->                                                               
    @on 'add:thumbnails', (thumbnail) => thumbnail.set 'gallery_id', @get('_id')

class Entities.Thumbnail extends Backbone.AssociatedModel
  idAttribute: '_id'
```

But I also have a collection of unused thumbnails :

```coffee
class Entities.UnusedThumbnails extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Entities.Thumbnail

  initialize: ->
    @on 'add', (thumbnail) -> thumbnail.set 'gallery_id', null
```

I can move thumbnails around between the gallery and the UnusedThumbnails collection just fine, but how do I persists them ?

If I just add a thumbnail from the UnusedThumbnails collection to the gallery thumbnails and save the gallery using :

```
gallery.save([], patch: true)
```

i get a 404 response saying "Document(s) not found for class Thumbnail with id(s) ..." which make sense since rails only search for a thumbnail with this id inside the gallery.

Same for removing thumbnails from the gallery, if I post the gallery with missing thumbnails the rails update method will just assume these thumbnails are unchanged.

Do I need to save each added / removed thumbnails separately?

What's the proper way to do this ?

Edit:
I realize I'll probably need to create a specialized update action, like update_strict (for lack of a better name)

```
def update_strict
  new_ids = gallery_params[:thumbnails_attributes].map(&:_id)
  existing_ids = @gallery.thumbnails_ids

  ids_to_add = new_ids - existing_ids
  ids_to_remove = existing_ids - new_ids

  @gallery.thumbnails.find(ids_to_remove).each |thumbnail| do
    thumbnail.gallery = nil
    thumbnail.save
  end

  ids_to_add.each |id| do
    thumbnail = Thumbnail.find(id)
    thumbnail_params = (gallery_params[:thumbnails_attributes].select { |t| t._id == id })[0]
    thumbnail.update(thumbnail_params)
  end

  gallery_params[:thumbnails_attributes].delete_if { |thumbnail| ids_to_add.include?(thumbnail._id) }

  respond_to do |format|
    if @gallery.update(gallery_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

But is there a proper, cleaner way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up overwriting `thumbnails_attributes=` in the Gallery model :

```
def thumbnails_attributes=thumbnails_attributes)
  ids = thumbnails_attributes.map { |t| t['id'] }
  (ids - thumbnail_ids).each do |id|
    thumbnail = Thumbnail.find id
    thumbnails << thumbnail
  end
  super(thumbnails_attributes)
end
```

This allow me to add existing thumbnails to the gallery.
The simplest way to allow their removal was to switch to [backbone-nested-attributes](https://github.com/dtmtec/backbone-nested-attributes) which add a _destroy attribute to destroyed models.